# Adding style "cursor:pointer" to a class item using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this following in my HTML:

```
 <div class="owl-item" style="width: 272px;">....</div>
 <div class="owl-item" style="width: 172px;">....</div>
 <div class="owl-item" style="width: 72px;">....</div>
 <div class="owl-item" style="width: 2px;">....</div>
```

Now i want to add the following style "cursor:pointer" to the items bearing the class "owl-item" and also when the div is clicked I want to navigate to a webpage. I achieved the latter but not getting a way to find the former.

I used:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".owl-item").click(function () {

            window.open ("../Gallery3.aspx");
        });


    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.owl-item').css('cursor', 'pointer');
});
```

You can also use this function to set multiple `CSS` properties by passing an object to it:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.owl-item').css({
         'cursor': 'pointer',
         'background-color': 'red',
    });
});
```

Finally, if you are not conditionally setting this `CSS` property, you better use `CSS` directly:

```
.owl-item {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```